# Seo: use iframe to improve code to text ratio?

Tags: html, iframe, seo

We often use widgets for our websites. For example, travel websites often use booking search widget that has a lot of code and the code to text ratio dramatically decrease.

What if I use iframe for all widgets and other things to hide them from search engine? It is a good idea, if I can remove about 30% of code in this way?

Comment: If you're worried about code to text ratios, you can dramatically increase the amount of text on your page by putting a load of text into a div (I recommend going to Project Gutenberg - they have loads of free texts there) and then hiding it from users using `display: none` or setting huge negative margins. Your SEO rankings will skyrocket, I promise! `</irony>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Code to text ratio is not something you need to be worrying about. It's not a factor and even if it were, it would be so small of a factor that you wouldn't notice it in the search results.
2. Doing this is attempting to manipulate the search rankings. That's a *huge* SEO no-no. If your site is reviewed it could be penalized.

Having widgets on a web page is common and normal. Don't worry about them affecting SEO. Just make sure they are something that your users want. That will have a much larger impact on your website's success.

Comment: 1. I read a lot that it is better to have high ratio...
2. If I create new websites, should I put big widgets to iframe, is it better?

Comment: Ignore wherever you read that. Much of the content about SEO on the Internet is complete nonsense. Stick to the basics. They really work. And implement the widget however it is meant to be implmeneted. Using an iframe won't help with SEO but it does hurt accessibility which is bad for some users.